# how to add a class with the end increment for the number of pictures I have to a mustache template in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, class, mustache, auto-increment

I have the follow mustache template:

```
<script id="pictures" type="text/template">
{{#images}}
  <li id="dndtemplate">
    <img src={{img}} title={{imgnimi}} alt={{imgnimi}} <span>{{imgnimi}}</span> 
  </li>
{{/images}}
</script>
```

---

and I have to add to the img tag a class "dnd" with auto increment for the number or images I have in the json file. I have done this way but it does not work.

```
$(function() {
 $.getJSON('image.json', function(image) {
   var template = $('#pictures').html(function(){
     for (var i = 0; i <= img.length[]; i++);
      $("#pictures").getElementsByTagName("img").addClass("dnd"+i);
      i++;
     });
     var html = Mustache.to_html(template, image);
     $('#dndtemplate').html()           

  }); //getJSON
}); //function</script>
```

---

json is here:

```
{ 
"images" : [
    {"img" : "images/tytto_60x80.png", 
    "imgnimi" : "Vilja"},
    {"img" : "images/tytto2_60x80.png", 
    "imgnimi" : "Katri"},
    {"img" : "images/tytto3_60x80.png", 
    "imgnimi" : "Mari"},
    {"img" : "images/tytto4_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Larissa"},
    {"img" : "images/tytto5_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Alice"},
    {"img" : "images/tytto6_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Helena"},
    {"img" : "images/poika1_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Jesse"},
    {"img" : "images/poika2_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Lauri"},
    {"img" : "images/poika3_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Petri"},
    {"img" : "images/poika4_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Joonas"},
    {"img" : "images/poika5_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Valtteri"},
    {"img" : "images/poika6_60x80.png",
    "imgnimi" : "Vesa"},    
    {"img" : "images/auto_110x60.png",
    "imgnimi" : "auto"}

]}
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mustache is logic-less templates, you can't apply the incremental logic over here. However there is some work around and following is the code.

First you need to update the template.

```
<script id="pictures" type="text/template">
  <li id="dndtemplate">
      <img src="{{img}}" title="{{imgnimi}}" alt="{{imgnimi}}" class="{{dndClass}}" /> <span> {{imgnimi}} </span> 
  </li>
</script>
```

Next you need to iterate over the returned JSON object.

```
var template = $("#pictures").html();
$.each(imgObj.images, function(i, data) {
    data.dndClass = "dnd"+i;
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#resultList').append(html);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/Pfzug/)**

I hope this works for you.

Comment: thank you for your time and help. Do you have any idea how to make the drag and drop work with this code? The pictures are for dragging. I was thinking to use a fancybox type jquery to make the pictures appear and the drop picture will need another template. Thank you again for your help and time

Comment: Well that is totally a different question after all, however if the above comment answers you question please mark it as an answer :)